# Why won't my chainsaw start?

Tags: small-engine, chainsaw

I have a Stihl something-or-other, and it reliably has the same problem:
It will start and run beautifully, then eventually it will no longer start, most likely due to too much oil in the mix, as the easy way to get it going again is to simply pull out the spark plug and hit it with a toothbrush, and then it starts right up again. So my theory is that the mix is condensing in the chamber whenever the engine is turned off long enough to cool, and the volatiles must somehow manage to evaporate, leaving behind a thin coating of oil on the spark gap surfaces, reducing their conductivity and thus ability to spark. However, as I stated previously; easy fix: toothbrush. The problem is, when the toothbrush trick no longer works!!! What's going on? I have probably spent the value of the saw in 'repairs' at the local shop, where they never remember what was wrong with it, they just put a new card-kit on it, and don't mind taking my money again. I believe I have become somewhat of a local joke at my own expense due to this. This problem occurs sometimes quickly, same day, sometimes it may take a week. What is the cause? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to [woodworking.se], please take the [tour] and look through what this site is about. I've requested that this be migrated to [mechanics.se] for you since it's got _NOTHING_ whatsoever to do with woodworking, you know, the topic of this site. [Mechanics.se] is all about _all_ engine maintenance and repair and they'll be able to help you. However, you'll still want to [edit] this question to add some formatting and read up on [how to ask a good question](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) if you want some help there.

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you use the fuel mix that's recommended in the owner's manual instead of a mix with too much oil in it? Also, please say what the business end of the plug looks like when you take it out, before you brush it.

Comment: 'Too much oil' is just a guess. We've always used the additive in the little bottle in the prescribed amount.

Comment: @user101434 OK, so it's not too much oil and it must be something else. Again, what does the plug look like before you brush it off? Oily carbon caked on? Dry carbon caked on? Something else? Please describe it the best you can.

Comment: Have you _replaced_ the spark plug? Have you check the gap?